# Find a bad diamond out of $3^k$ taking $2k$ comparisons

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Question:

There is a collection of $n > 1$ diamonds, consisting of $n — 1$ good diamonds and one
bad diamond. All good diamonds have the same weight, while the bad diamond is
either lighter or heavier than a good diamond. You have a scale that allows you
to compare the weights of any two (disjoint) subsets of the diamonds. Note that
if $n = 1$ then the diamond in the set is bad.

(a) Show that if $n = 3$, then we can identify the bad diamond using the
scale at most twice.

(b) Show the following by mathematical induction: For any $k > 0$, the
bad diamond in a collection of $3^k$ diamonds can be identified using the scale
at most $2k$ times.

Solution:

- Base case: if we have $3$ diamonds ($abc$) then we can find the bad diamond by at most 2 comparisons ($ab$ and $bc$)
- Induction hypothesis: Let $P(k)$ be the statement: "we can identify the bad diamond in a collection of $3^k$ diamond using the scale at most $2k$ times".
- We want to prove $P(k+1)$ or "we can identify the bad diamond in a collection of $3^{k+1}$ diamond using the scale at most $2\times(k+1)$ times".

We can use the fact that $3^{k+1} = 3 \times 3^{k} = 3^k + 3^k + 3^k$ then we apply induction hypothesis on each of $3$ sets and we get $2k + 2k + 2k = 3 \times 2^k \not = 2 \times (k+1)$

So basically we divide the $3^{k+1}$ into 3 groups and using the induction hypothesis for each group we find the total number of comparisons needed and then add them up.

I am lost. I can't prove this.

Comment: "Note that if $n=1$ then the diamond in the set is bad." This is impossible, for it is assumed that $n>1$.

Answer (score 2):

Call the 3 large sets of size $3^k$ $A,\ B$ and $C$. Then compare $(A,B)$ and $(B,C)$, you now have found a pile of size of size $3^k$ which contains the bad diamond, which you can filter in $2k$ moves. So the total number of comparisons was $2+2k = 2(k+1)$, following the same strategy you used for the base case.

Comment: I don't understand this. We run the comparisons on $A$ and we see if it contains any bad ones or not. If there is then we are done. Otherwise, we run comparisons on $B$ and see if there are bad ones or not. If there is then we are done. Otherwise, we run comparisons on $C$ and see if there are bad ones or not. This is $3 \times 2^k$. Please clarify.

Comment: How do you now which one is the bad diamond in the case $k=1$? Now apply this to the case for cases where $k\geq 2$. You have now determined which one is "the bad pile", in stead of the bad diamond. You can repeat this subdivision until you only have piles left of size $1$, effectively returning to the base case.

Comment: Somehow I think we should be able to do this with fewer than 2k comparisons, at least for large k.

Answer (score 0):

We can do better than this. If $n = 1$ or $n = 2$ then we cannot find the bad diamond. If $2^{k-1} < n ≤ 2^k$ for $k ≥ 2$ then we can find the bad diamond in k weighings. This is an improvement for $n = 3^3 = 27$ with k = 5 instead of k = 6, for $n = 3^4 = 81$ with k = 7 instead of k = 8, for $n = 3^5 = 243$ with k = 8 instead of k = 10 and so on.

Proof: We can obviously not determine the bad diamond if n = 1 or n = 2. Induction starts with k = 2 and n = 3 or n = 4. We name the diamonds A, B and C or A, B, C and D. We weigh A vs. B. If A ≠ B then one of A and B is bad and C is good; we weigh A vs C to find which one of A and B is the bad one. If A = B then A, B are both good. If n = 3 then we found the bad one C with one weighing, otherwise either C or D are bad and we weigh A vs C to find out which one.

Otherwise we have $2^k < n ≤ 2 \cdot 2^k$ diamonds and want to find the bad one with k+1 weighings. We split the diamonds into 3 groups A, B and C. If $2^k < n ≤ 1.5 \cdot 2^k$ then A and B contain $0.25 \cdot 2^k$ diamonds each, C contains the remaining n' diamonds with $0.5 \cdot 2^k < n' ≤ 2^k$. If $1.5 \cdot 2^k < n ≤ 2 \cdot 2^k$ then A and B contain $0.5 \cdot 2^k$ diamonds each, C again contains the remaining n' diamonds with $0.5 \cdot 2^k < n' ≤ 2^k$. In each case C contains more diamonds than either A or B.

We weigh A vs. B. If A = B then A and B contain all good diamonds and C contains a bad one. By induction we find the bad diamond with k weighings for a total of k+1 weighings. If A ≠ B then we know either $0.5 \cdot 2^k$ or $2^k$ diamonds containing the bad one and we have more than $0.5 \cdot 2^k$ known good diamonds. As long as the group containing a possibly bad diamond contains more than one, we split the group in half and weigh one half against the same number of known good ones in C. As a result, each weighing reduces the set containing the bad diamond by half. After at most k weighings only one diamond is left which is bad, so we found the bad diamond in a total of k+1 weighings.